# Is possible download file from drive.google without credentials

Tags: c#, google-api, credentials

I searched this subject at many web pages and I tried; but every time web page verification window appears. Already I have ClientId and SecretKey. Is that not enough? I want to do this with c# but without credential.

Comment: Welcome to SO. You will need to update your question with more information about your use case. The simple answer to your question is "it is possible only if the file is public". Once you have explained your use case, you can get better answers.

Comment: My file is public on google drive. Even so confirmation webpage appearing. Also, How better can I ask question? If you suggest me a question then I will change the question.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be via the C# api. You can create an api key and use the library to download files by authenticating with that api key

[Google Drive .NET api](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/apis/drive/v3)

Comment: Did you look the example of this? There's credential. A few hours before, I tried this. Opening web page for authentication. If possible can you share an example code or can you prepare an example project?

Comment: Because the users in my software should not bother with authentication.

Comment: I'll check later

Comment: Is there any improvement? @JanFeyen